# exit cordova Windows 10 application

Tags: angularjs, windows, cordova, uwp, windows-10-universal

When i use my cordova app in the home page, i need to display message to user to ask him if he really want to exit app or not.
Than i need to exit app if user select "yes".

To do it, i use this code :

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {
    $rootScope.back();
    $rootScope.$apply();
}, false);

$rootScope.back = function(execute) {
    var path = $location.$$path;
    if (path !== '/') {
        $location.path(path.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/'));
    } else {
        $rootScope.exitApp();
    }
}.bind(this);

$rootScope.exitApp = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit('showPopover', {
        message: $rootScope.LABELS.QUIT_APP,
        confirmCallback: function() {
            if (typeof navigator.app !== 'undefined') {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
        },
        cancelCallback: doNothing
    });
};
```

It's working in android and iOS, but not in Windows 10 app.

In W10, `navigator.app` is undefined.
I read that i'm supposed to suspend app and not exit it, so i tried this windows quirkswritten in cordova doc (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#backbutton) :

```
$rootScope.exitApp = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit('showPopover', {
        message: $rootScope.LABELS.QUIT_APP,
        confirmCallback: function() {
            if (typeof navigator.app !== 'undefined') {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
            else if (platformUtils.isWindows()) {
                throw new Error('Exit'); // This will suspend the app
            }
        },
        cancelCallback: doNothing
    });
};
```

`throw new Error('Exit')` is called and display error in logs, but app is not suspended.

Maybe because i'm in a angular app?

Does any one has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is due to `$emit` used to display popover.
If i throw error on popover callback, this error is not returned to `backbutton` event callback.

But, on windows platform, we are not supposed to display popover to ask if user is sure to want to leave app, so if I add it to "back" function, it's working.

Final code used to Windows 10 app is :

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {
    $rootScope.back();
    $rootScope.$apply();
}, false);

$rootScope.back = function(execute) {
    var path = $location.$$path;
    if (path !== '/') {
        $location.path(path.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/'));
    } else {
        if (window.device.platform.toLowerCase() === 'windows') {
            throw new Error('Exit'); // This will suspend the app
        } else {
            $rootScope.exitApp();
        }
    }
}.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this:

```
if (device.platform.toLowerCase() === "windows") {
    //this closes the app and leaves a message in the windows system eventlog if error object is provided
    MSApp.terminateApp();
} else {
    navigator.app.exitApp()
}
```